# Using linq to append list to list from select method

Tags: list, linq, addrange

I have a collection A of let's say 100 items. From that list I want to perform a where clause which can rule out let's say 20 of items.

Is there a way to use Select clause or something else on items in which I could use external method that returns 2 items.

I would need to end up with 160 objects from the original list.

What I currently have is

```
public List<A> ToAList(B item)
{ 
   return new List<A> {new A(), new A()}; 
}
```

If I make this call

```
originalList.Where(x => true).Select(y => ToAList(y)).ToList();
```

I end up having a list of 80 (from pseudo example) two-item A lists instead of a list containing 160 objects A.

I am looking for a way to avoid loops. Just plain Select or AddRange trick that could result in one list.

Comment: If `ToAList` does only that you could replace it with: `Enumerable.Range(0, originalList.Count * 2).Select(i => new A()).ToList();`

Comment: It does a lot more but I wanted to have it written in such a way just to have a point. SelectMany does the trick as @Peter B wrote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany):

```
originalList.Where(x => true).SelectMany(y => ToAList(y)).ToList();
```

Comment: Just beat me a minute too soon to answer my own question :)